# Queue structure's enqueue does not work or does it

Tags: c++, queue

Had a test, the idea was to make two queue's who then merge and create a third, sorted queue. The problem surfaced when I made the structure and tried entering the both queue's through enqueue method I made in it's class. My idea was to make two arrays alongside the two queue's and ultimately then create a third array consisting of both of these arrays, whom I'd sort and run through a loop and enqueue into the third queue. But when I checked the values to see what is contained in the two arrays, I got a strange list of values return. I don't seem to be able to spot the issue myself, is it in the structure of Queue or the main method.
Examined this code a few times and I'm dead lost. Would appreciate any feedback.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int const siz = 1000;
template<typename T>

class Queue{
private:
    int f, r,n;
    T* qArray;
public:
    Queue();
    ~Queue();
    void enqueue(const T& i);
    int dequeue(T& i);
    Queue(const Queue& B);
    Queue& operator=(const Queue& B);
    T front(){
        if(isEmpty()){
            cout<<"This is an empty queue"<<endl;
            return 1;
        }
        return qArray[f];
    }
    int size() const {
    return n;
    }
    bool isEmpty() const {
    return n == 0;
    }
};

template<typename T>
 Queue<T>::Queue(){
    qArray = new T[siz];
    n = 0;
    f = 0;
    r = 0;
}
template<typename T>
Queue<T>::~Queue(){
delete [] qArray;
}
template<typename T>
Queue<T>& Queue<T>::operator=(const Queue<T> & B){
    if(this != & B){
        delete [] qArray;
        copyQueue(B);
    }
    return *this;
}
template<typename T>
void Queue<T>::enqueue(const T& a){
    if(n == siz){

        cout<<"Impossible"<<endl;
    } else{
        qArray[r] = a;
        n++;
        r++;
        r = r%siz; 
    }
}
template<typename T>
int Queue<T>::dequeue(T& a){
    if(n > 0)
    {
        a = qArray[f];
        n--;
        f++;
        f = f % siz;
        return 1;
    }
}

int main() {
    Queue<int> qOne;
    Queue<int> qThree;
    cout<<"Please enter the first queue of numbers in a growing order(press a zero if you want to stop): "<<endl;
    int a[siz];
    while(siz){
        int n = 0;
        int i = 0;
        cin>>n;
        qOne.enqueue(n);
        i++;
        if(n <= 0 || !n)
        {
            cout<<"Ending the queue one's entry"<<endl;
            qOne.dequeue(n);
            break;
        }
        a[i] = n;
    }
    Queue<int> qTwo;
    cout<<"Please enter the second queue of numbers in a growing order(press a zero if you want to stop): "<<endl;
    int b[siz];
    while(siz){
        int n;
        int i = 0;
        cin>>n;
        if(!n)
        {
            cout<<"Ending the queue two's entry"<<endl;
            break;
        }
        qTwo.enqueue(n);
        b[i] = n;
        i++;
    }
    int n = qOne.size();
    int m = qTwo.size();
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    int c[siz];
    while(i < n)
    {
        c[k] = a[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while(j < m)
    {
        c[k] = b[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n+m; i++)
    {
        cout<<c[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cout<<b[i]<<" ";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't ignore the warnings: *75:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function* this logic mistake will be fatal.

Comment: Examining code is a start, but very often any bad assumptions you made while writing the program will be carried through to the examination. Instead run the program through a debugger. If you step through the program line-by-line and keep an eye out for where your assumptions are violated you'll find bugs more efficiently.

Comment: There are many many errors in your code. I will anser the question, but you need to give me at least 2 hours to work on that . . .

Answer (score 0):

First: I do think that you misunderstand the problem. You want to have 2 queues and then create from that a 3rd queue with sorted values from both input queues. But of course, **without** separate arrays.

If you use separate arrays, then you would need no queues at all.

Then, you have 0 comments and more then ugly variable names, without any meaning, so that you will have forgotten everything in 2 weeks. This alone leads to a code quality of 0.

All variables shall be initialized. Always. User input needs to be checked. Always.

Then you have severe problems with your input handling. The input of 0 will terminate the loop. Nothing else. So, we can easily go out of bounds.

Please check. You have `while` loops with a constant value in it. Your compiler tells you this error. So, please enable all compiler warnings, maximum possible level.

Now. Let’s analyze your code line by line. I added comments with errors.

The semantic error on solving the given task is not mentioned at all.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;     // This should never be used. Do not open the complete namespace

int const siz = 1000;   // Bad variable name. And, should be constexpr. But in the end a capacity and not a size should be used

template<typename T>    // For whatever. Anyway

class Queue {
private:
    int f, r, n;   // Variable names without any meaning. What is it. And no initialization
    T* qArray;
public:
    Queue();
    ~Queue();
    void enqueue(const T& i);
    int dequeue(T& i);             // Why does it return an int? Function should be void and return a T
    Queue(const Queue& B);
    Queue& operator=(const Queue& B);

    T front() {      // Front? are you sure?
        if (isEmpty()) {
            cout << "This is an empty queue" << endl;  // Why separrate endl? Not needed
            return 1;                                  // Should be written to std::cerr
        }
        return qArray[f];     // What is f?
    }
    int size() const {   // Is n the capacity or the number of elements in the queue
        return n;
    }
    bool isEmpty() const {
        return n == 0;
    }
};

template<typename T>
Queue<T>::Queue() {
    qArray = new T[siz];  // The queue is not dynamic. It has a capacity with a magic number
    n = 0;                // What again is n,r,f? I forgot it already
    f = 0;
    r = 0;
}
template<typename T>
Queue<T>::~Queue() {
    delete[] qArray;
}
template<typename T>
Queue<T>& Queue<T>::operator=(const Queue<T>& B) {
    if (this != &B) {
        delete[] qArray;
        copyQueue(B);
    }
    return *this;
}
template<typename T>
void Queue<T>::enqueue(const T& a) {
    if (n == siz) {

        cout << "Impossible" << endl;   // Do not use endl. Output to std::cerr
        // And grow your memory dynamically
    }
    else {
        qArray[r] = a;   // What is r?
        n++;             // Why n and r?
        r++;
        r = r % siz;    // What is that. I do not understand the intended meaning 
    }
}
template<typename T>
int Queue<T>::dequeue(T& a) {  // Compiler gives you a waring. One rturn path is missing
    if (n > 0)                 // What are you returning
    {
        a = qArray[f];      // What is f?
        n--;
        f++;
        f = f % siz;        // Why that, what do you want to achieve?
        return 1;           // What is the magic number 1? What is the meaning?
    }
}

int main() {
    Queue<int> qOne;        // No initialization
    Queue<int> qThree;      // No initialization  
     cout << "Please enter the first queue of numbers in a growing order(press a zero if you want to stop): " << endl;
    int a[siz];             // Why a spearte array?
    while (siz) {           // Size is a constant. This will result in always true. This is an endless loop
        int n = 0;          // You set n and i in each loop to 0. So always i will be 0
        int i = 0;
        cin >> n;
        qOne.enqueue(n);
        i++;                // Since you set i t0 0 before, i will now always be one01
        if (n <= 0 || !n)
        {
            cout << "Ending the queue one's entry" << endl;
            qOne.dequeue(n);
            break;           // OK, breaking the endless loop   
        }
        a[i] = n;            // i will always be 1 here. Nevr something different
}


    Queue<int> qTwo; // Same as above
    cout << "Please enter the second queue of numbers in a growing order(press a zero if you want to stop): " << endl;
    int b[siz];
    while (siz) {
        int n;
        int i = 0;
        cin >> n;
        if (!n)
        {
            cout << "Ending the queue two's entry" << endl;
            break;
        }
        qTwo.enqueue(n);
        b[i] = n;
        i++;
    }

    int n = qOne.size();
    int m = qTwo.size();
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    int c[siz];   // Hardcode magic number C-style array
    while (i < n)
    {
        c[k] = a[i];  // In array a, only index one will be have a value. The rest contains garbage
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < m)
    {
        c[k] = b[j];// In array b, only index one will be have a value. The rest contains garbage
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    // Now, a,b,c conatins garbage values.
    for (int i = 0; i < n + m; i++)
    {
        cout << c[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cout << b[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ok. Now, how to fix? We split bigger problems into smaller problems. Let us start with the queue. We will add dynamic memory management and throw away the fixed size.

This we will achieve with setting an initial capacity (do not mix up with number of elements in the queue). If we want to add a value, and the number of elements would grow above the capacity, we will do a reallocation. Meaning, we double the previous capacity, the allocate a new temporary dynamic array, copy all values from the old array to the new temporary array, delete the old array and then assign the temp array to the old array pointer.

Then, we need to decide which typical functions a queue would have. Those are:

- **front**, access the first element
- **back**, access the last element
- **push**, inserts element at the end
- **pop**, remove first element
- **empty**, checks, whether the queue is empty
- **size** checks, how many elements are in the queue

In code. Such a minimal queue could look like that:

```
#include <iostream>

// Iitial capacity of queue, will be double, if additional memory is needed
constexpr unsigned int InitialCapacity = 4u;

template <typename T>
class Queue {

    unsigned int capacity{ InitialCapacity };               // Capacity of the queue. That many elements may fit into the queue
    unsigned int numberOfElements{ 0 };                     // Number of elements currently in the queue
    T* data{ nullptr };                                     // Underlying container for our data

public:
    // Ctor and Dtor
    Queue() { data = new T[capacity]; }                     // Default constructor
    ~Queue() { delete[] data; }                             // Release previously allocated memory

    // Capacity
    bool empty() const { return numberOfElements == 0; }    // Function to check, if there is data available or not
    unsigned int size() const { return numberOfElements; }  // And return the number of elements in the queue

    // Element access
    T front() { return empty() ? 0 : data[0]; };
    T back() { return empty() ? 0 : data[numberOfElements - 1]; }

    // Modifiers
    void push(const T& t) {                                    // Add an element at the end
        if (numberOfElements >= capacity) {                     // Check, if we need more memory than our capacity is
            capacity *= 2;                                      // Need more memory. Double the capacity
            T* temp = new T[capacity];                          // Get new memory
            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < numberOfElements; ++k) // Copy old data to tempdata
                temp[k] = data[k];
            delete[] data;                                      // Delete old memory
            data = temp;                                        // And assign temp meory back to our data pointer
        }
        data[numberOfElements++] = t;                           // Now, add the new data andincrement our internal counter
    }
    void pop() {                                                // Remove the first element
        if (not empty()) {                                      // Do only, if not empty
            --numberOfElements;                                 // Now, we have one lement less
            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < numberOfElements; ++k) // Shift all elements in our internbal array one to the left
                data[k] = data[k + 1];
        }
    }
};

int main() { // Test code
    Queue<int> q{};
    q.push(1); q.push(2); q.push(3); q.push(4); q.push(5);
    while (not q.empty()) {
        std::cout << q.front() << '\n';
        q.pop();
    }
}
```

Good. This is now a fully dynamic queue with basically all needed functionality.

Let us look at main now. You should modify your code and ask the user, how many values to enter. And then read this number of values in a loop. We need to add also input checking here. And additionally, because we do need this functionality twice, we will put it into a function.

Some explanation about input validation. You may have heard that a formatted input function like `cin > x` will again return a reference to the stream on which they have been called. So, the above statement will return `cin`. With that mechanisms it is possible to make chained statements like in `cin >> x >> y` which s`hould be read as` (cin >> x) >> y’. Ok. Understood. But now how to validate the input?

`cin > x` will try to convert the value given by the user to ‘x’. If this does not work, then it will set an internal error state.

And since, for all stream, the bool operator is overwritten in a way, that it returns the state, you can simple write `if (cin)` to check, if the stream is OK. Or, as explained above, you should write: `if (cin >> x)`.

Good let’s make an input function. One of many many possible solutions:

```
template <typename T>
void readQueueData(Queue<T>& q) {

   bool readActionOK{};

   do {
       // We assue that everything works well
       readActionOK = true ;

       // Give information to user. Tell him what to do
       std::cout << "\n\nNow going to enter values in a queue.\n\nHow many values to you want to enter?\n";

       // Read, how many values to enter
       unsigned int numberOfValuesToEnter{};
       if ((std::cin >> numberOfValuesToEnter) and (numberOfValuesToEnter > 0)) {

           // Now read the values and add to the queue
           T value{};
           unsigned int k = 0; 
           while (k < numberOfValuesToEnter) {
               if (std::cin >> value) {
                   q.push(value);      // No problem. Store data in queue
                   ++k;                // Read next value. We only increment k here on success.
               }
               else {
                   std::cerr << "\n\nError while reading queue data. Please try again\n\n";
                   std::cin.clear();   // Reset state of stream and get rid of trash
                   std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
               }
           }
       }
       else {
           readActionOK = false;
           std::cerr << "\n\nError: Problem while reading number of values to input\n\n";
           std::cin.clear();       // Reset state of stream and get rid of trash
           std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
       }
   } while (not readActionOK);
}
```

For sorting I added a simple bubble sort function to the Queue class. Maybe you need a different algorithm.

But I do not have more detailed information. So, I go like this.

Complete solution could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

// Initial capacity of queue, will be double, if additional memory is needed
constexpr unsigned int InitialCapacity = 4u;

template <typename T>
class Queue {

    unsigned int capacity{ InitialCapacity };               // Capacity of the queue. That many elements may fit into the queue
    unsigned int numberOfElements{ 0 };                     // Number of elements currently in the queue
    T* data{ nullptr };                                     // Underlying container for our data

public:
    // Ctor and Dtor
    Queue() { data = new T[capacity]; }                     // Default constructor
    ~Queue() { delete[] data; }                             // Release previously allocated memory

    // Capacity
    bool empty() const { return numberOfElements == 0; }    // Function to check, if there is data available or not
    unsigned int size() const { return numberOfElements; }  // And return the number of elements in the queue

    // Element access
    T front() { return empty() ? 0 : data[0]; };
    T back() { return empty() ? 0 : data[numberOfElements - 1]; }

    // Modifiers
    void push(const T& t) {                                    // Add an element at the end
        if (numberOfElements >= capacity) {                     // Check, if we need more memory than our capacity is
            capacity *= 2;                                      // Need more memory. Double the capacity
            T* temp = new T[capacity];                          // Get new memory
            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < numberOfElements; ++k) // Copy old data to tempdata
                temp[k] = data[k];
            delete[] data;                                      // Delete old memory
            data = temp;                                        // And assign temp meory back to our data pointer
        }
        data[numberOfElements++] = t;                           // Now, add the new data andincrement our internal counter
    }
    void pop() {                                                // Remove the first element
        if (not empty()) {                                      // Do only, if not empty
            --numberOfElements;                                 // Now, we have one lement less
            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < numberOfElements; ++k) // Shift all elements in our internbal array one to the left
                data[k] = data[k + 1];
        }
    }
    
    void sort() {                                               // Very simply bubble sort
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfElements - 1; i++)
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < numberOfElements - i - 1; j++)
                if (data[j] > data[j + 1]) {
                    T temp = data[j];
                    data[j] = data[j + 1];
                    data[j + 1] = temp;
                }
    }
 };


template <typename T>
void readQueueData(Queue<T>& q) {

    bool readActionOK{};

    do {
        // We assue that everything works well
        readActionOK = true ;

        // Give information to user. Tell him what to do
        std::cout << "\n\nNow going to enter values in a queue.\n\nHow many values to you want to enter?\n\n";

        // Read, how many values to enter
        unsigned int numberOfValuesToEnter{};
        if ((std::cin >> numberOfValuesToEnter) and (numberOfValuesToEnter > 0)) {

            // Now read the values and add to the queue
            T value{};
            unsigned int k = 0; 
            while (k < numberOfValuesToEnter) {
                if (std::cin >> value) {
                    q.push(value);      // No problem. Store data in queue
                    ++k;                // Read next value. We only increment k here on success.
                }
                else {
                    std::cerr << "\n\nError while reading queue data. Please try again\n\n";
                    std::cin.clear();   // Reset state of stream and get rid of trash
                    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            readActionOK = false;
            std::cerr << "\n\nError: Problem while reading number of values to input\n\n";
            std::cin.clear();       // Reset state of stream and get rid of trash
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    } while (not readActionOK);
}

int main() { // Test code

    // Define the queues
    Queue<int> queueOne{};
    Queue<int> queueTwo{};
    
    // Read data into the queues
    readQueueData(queueOne);
    readQueueData(queueTwo);

    // Merge
    Queue<int> queueResult{};

    while (not queueOne.empty()) {
        queueResult.push(queueOne.front());
        queueOne.pop();
    }
    while (not queueTwo.empty()) {
        queueResult.push(queueTwo.front());
        queueTwo.pop();
    }
    // Sort
    queueResult.sort();

    // Show result
    std::cout << "\n\nResult:\n\n";
    while (!queueResult.empty()) {
        std::cout << queueResult.front() << '\n';
        queueResult.pop();
    }
}
```

---

And here a more efficient soulution for a queue using an underlying linked list:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Queue {

    struct Node {
        T data{};
        Node* next;
    };
    Node* head = nullptr;
    Node* tail = nullptr;

    unsigned int numberOfElements{ 0 };                     // Number of elements currently in the queue
    
public:
    // Ctor and Dtor
    Queue() { }                     // Default constructor
    ~Queue() { clear(); }                             // Release previously allocated memory

    // Capacity
    bool empty() const { return head == nullptr; }    // Function to check, if there is data available or not
    unsigned int size() const { return numberOfElements; }  // And return the number of elements in the queue

    // Element access
    T front() { return empty() ? T{} : head->data; };
    T back() { return empty() ? T{} : tail->data; }

    // Modifiers
    void push(const T& t) {
        Node* temp = new Node{t, nullptr};
        if (head == nullptr)
            head = tail = temp;
        else {
            tail->next = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
        ++numberOfElements;                           // Now, add the new data andincrement our internal counter
    }
    void pop() {                                                // Remove the first element
        if (head != nullptr) {
            Node* temp = head->next;
            delete head;
            head = temp;
            --numberOfElements;
        }
    }
    void clear() {
        Node* iterator = head;
        while (iterator) {
            Node* temp = iterator->next;
            delete iterator;
            iterator = temp;
        }
        head = tail = nullptr;
        numberOfElements = 0;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Queue& q) {
        Node* iterator = q.head;
        while (iterator) {
            Node* temp = iterator->next;
            os << iterator->data << '\n';
            iterator = temp;
        }
        return os;
    }
};

template <typename T>
void readQueueData(Queue<T>& q) {

    bool readActionOK{};

    do {
        // We assue that everything works well
        readActionOK = true;

        // Give information to user. Tell him what to do
        std::cout << "\n\nNow going to enter values in a queue.\n\nHow many values to you want to enter?\n\n";

        // Read, how many values to enter
        unsigned int numberOfValuesToEnter{};
        if ((std::cin >> numberOfValuesToEnter) and (numberOfValuesToEnter > 0)) {

            // Now read the values and add to the queue
            T value{};
            unsigned int k = 0;
            while (k < numberOfValuesToEnter) {
                if (std::cin >> value) {
                    q.push(value);      // No problem. Store data in queue
                    ++k;                // Read next value. We only increment k here on success.
                }
                else {
                    std::cerr << "\n\nError while reading queue data. Please try again\n\n";
                    std::cin.clear();   // Reset state of stream and get rid of trash
                    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            readActionOK = false;
            std::cerr << "\n\nError: Problem while reading number of values to input\n\n";
            std::cin.clear();       // Reset state of stream and get rid of trash
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    } while (not readActionOK);
}
int main() { // Test code

    // Define the queues
    Queue<int> queueOne{};
    Queue<int> queueTwo{};

    // Read data into the queues
    readQueueData(queueOne);
    readQueueData(queueTwo);

     // Show data
    std::cout << "\n\nData queue 1:\n\n" << queueOne << "\n\n";
    std::cout << "\n\nData queue 2:\n\n" << queueTwo << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Alright, as for cleaeing a few things up, I mentioned this was simply a test (had to work on the code for 80 minutes, nothing more) and not a part of a bigger problem/project that I worked on. So that's why I used f, r and n names instead of front, rear and size. As for the part where r%siz or f%siz, I know it may sound stupid, but that's how my teacher realized the queue first time we did it, so I just tried making it according to his approach. But i=0 is my dumbest mistake in while .And I just wanna thank you for clearing so many things up, I learned a great deal of things today!